# React - setting state with data does not work/ sets its to an empty array - why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I am trying to iterate through data and displaying it in my react app. My code works until I store the results in the the components state. Somehow (I marked it insight the code as 'HERE IT DOESNT WORK ANYMORE' as its hard to explain. I have rewrote my actual code because I didn't want to post hundreds of lines of code here :) and also exchanged the data (which I am actually receiving making an http request) with an object (which I only resized) - so please don't pay attention if some parts of the code look weird/too much as my actual code is much bigger. I also added a codepen link here-where you can't see anything (because its not working) but I included console.logs so you can see what I mean. Thank you very much for any help!!

https://codepen.io/helloocoding/pen/vWVLmp?editors=1010

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: PricedItineraries,
            result: []
        }
        this.handleInput = this.handleInput.bind(this);
        this.showSearchResults = this.showSearchResults.bind(this);
    }

    showSearchResults(obj) {
        console.log("func", this.state.data)
        var allTrips = [];
        var TotalPriceTemp = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
            var o = obj[i];
            allTrips.push(o.AirItinerary.OriginDestinationOptions.OriginDestinationOption)

            var totalFair = o.AirItineraryPricingInfo.PTC_FareBreakdowns.PTC_FareBreakdown.PassengerFare.TotalFare;
            TotalPriceTemp.push(totalFair.Amount);
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < allTrips.length; i++) {
            var MarketingAirlineTo = [];
            var MarketingAirlineBack = [];
            var TotalPrice = 0;
            var oneWay = allTrips[i][0];
            var returnTrip = allTrips[i][1];

            oneWay.FlightSegment.forEach(function (flightTo) {
                MarketingAirlineTo.push(flightTo.MarketingAirline.Code);
            })

            returnTrip.FlightSegment.forEach(function (flightTo) {
                MarketingAirlineBack.push(flightTo.MarketingAirline.Code)
            })

            TotalPriceTemp.forEach(function (item) {
                TotalPrice += item;
            })
            var tempFlightsObject = [];

            tempFlightsObject.push({
                marketingAirlineTo: MarketingAirlineTo,
                marketingAirlineBack: MarketingAirlineBack,
                TotalPrice: TotalPriceTemp[i]
            })
            console.log("tempFlightsObject", tempFlightsObject)
            this.setState({
                result: tempFlightsObject
            })
            console.log("result", this.state.result)
            //HERE IT DOESNT WORK ANYMORE: TEMPFLIGHTOBJECT shows correct data, but result doesn't
        }
    }

    handleInput() {
        console.log("handeInput func", this.state.data)
        this.showSearchResults(this.state.data);
        console.log("handeInput func -result", this.state.result)
    }

    render() {
        const flights = this.state.result.map((item, i) => {
            return (
                <div>
                    <div key={i}><p> {item.marketingAirlineTo} </p></div>
                </div>
            )
        })

        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.handleInput}>click me</button>
                <div> {flights}</div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}


React.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setState` is an asynchronous function. React batches updates together for performance reasons. See https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate for more information.

Your component should re-render, but you may not be able to log the state immediately after you set it. If you want, you can add a callback as the second argument to `setState`, which takes `state` as its first and only argument.

Answer (score 3):

**`setState` may be executed asynchronously** by react to batch updates and optimize performance.

---

You can **provide a callback to `setState`**, which will be called once the update has actually been completed:

```
this.setState({
    result: tempFlightsObject
}, function () { console.log("result", this.state.result) })
```

Answer (score 1):

`setState` may be batched.

`this.setState({ result: tempFlightsObject }, () => {
    console.log("result", this.state.result)
})`

will work